# What's the most efficient way to access sibling dictionary value in a Python dict?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, list-comprehension

In Python, I've got a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
matchings = [
    {'id': 'someid1', 'domain': 'somedomain1.com'},
    {'id': 'someid2', 'domain': 'somedomain2.com'},
    {'id': 'someid3', 'domain': 'somedomain3.com'}
]
```

and, I have a variable:

```
the_id = 'someid3'
```

What's the most efficient way to retrieve the domain value of the item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
domains = [matching['domain'] for matching in matchings if matching['id'] == the_id]
```

Which follows the format standard format of:

```
resulting_list = [item_to_return for item in items if condition]
```

And basically encapsulates all the following functionality:

```
domains = []
for matching in matchings:
    if matching['id'] == the_id:
        domains.append(matching['domain'])
```

All that functionality is represented in a single line using list comprehensions.

Comment: Perfect it may be, but is it efficient? What's the length of matchings? Take a look at S.Lott's answer too.

Comment: Is there some reason to use such a long names?  `[m['domain'] for m in matchings if m['id'] == the_id]`

Comment: I suspect that the request for "efficiency" was more to do with a nice, clean way to do it.

Comment: Yes, specifically, the code will be used in ZPT, where I don't have access to a typical Pythonic environment, and am very limited.  This works perfectly, in that sense.

Comment: If I stumbled on the list comprehension in code I was working on, I'd be wondering WTF for several minutes?  The code below it is so much more readable....

Comment: @Mark0978, That's fairly subjective since list comprehensions have been around a long time in Python, are well document, and are widely used.  They're not "clever coding", they're just a way to simplify the common task of building lists using the "for loop and if statement" combination.  I suspect you just haven't used them much, otherwise you'd find it just as easy, if not easier, to read.

Answer (score 2):

I'd restructure `matchings`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
matchings_ix= defaultdict(list)
for m in matchings:
    matchings_ix[m['id']].append( m )
```

Now the most efficient lookup is

```
matchings_ix[ d ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I can figure is to do an explicit search.  This is one area where I get disappointed in Python is that it doesn't give you a strong set of decoupled building blocks like in the C++ STL algorithms

```
[d["domain"] for d in matchings if d["id"] == "someid3"]
```

Comment: I do get this output: `[somedomain3.com]`, and if I want this output, without the brackets `somedomain3.com`, you could do `[d["domain"] for d in matchings if d["id"] == "someid3"][0]`

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there are dictionaries in the list doesn't really matter - the problem reduces to finding an item in a list where some property is true. To that end, some variation on @Soviut's answer is the way to go: loop or list comprehension, examining each of the items until a match is found. There's no inherent ordering of the items, so you couldn't even rely on something as helpful as [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html).

Answer (score 0):

I really like to use [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) in this sort of situation. It takes a function and an iterable and returns the list of elements where the function returns True (in Python 3.x it returns an iterator).

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x['id'] == 'someid3', matchings)
<<< [{'domain': 'somedomain3.com', 'id': 'someid3'}]
```

You could get a list of all domains by using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x['domain'] for x in filter(lambda x: x['id'] == 'someid3', matchings)]
<<< ['somedomain3.com']
```